# VBA - Get Index of Table depending on Values in the cells

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, word-table

i want to get the indexnumber of a table in word depending on values in the `cell(1,2) and cell(1,1)` and then i want to Autofitwindow this table.
I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
Dim wApp As Object
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim wDoc As Object
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 To wDoc.Tables.Count
    If wDoc.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Value = "Value1" And wDoc.Tables(i).Cell(1, 2).Value = "Value2" Then
       wDoc.Tables(i).AutoFitBehavior (2)
    End If
Next
```

but it doesnt work..does someone find the syntaxerror?

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: `wDoc` is never `Set`.

Comment: i tried ```Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(/pathname)``` but still doesnt work

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Object doesnt support this property or method..and the debugger shows this line:
```wDoc.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Value = "Value1" And wDoc.Tables(i).Cell(1, 2).Value = "Value2" Then```

Comment: `.Range.Text` instead of `.Value` I believe.

Comment: I believe the same

Comment: yes, the error doesnt pop up anymore. but the table isnt fittet. Now i tried to msgbox the value in cell(1,1) and it says "Value 1" and a small rectangle.. maybe its beacuse of the cell end character in every cell? (the small thing that looks like a small sea-mine :-D)

Comment: At the end of a cell, the range.text will include a chrw(13) (paragraph mark) followed by a chrw(7) (a cell mark/small sea mine).

Answer (score 0):

You need to eliminate the end-of-cell marker, which appears as the '¤' symbol and is comprised of the Chr(13) & Chr(7) combination. Try:

```
Dim wApp As Object, wDoc As Object, i As Long
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wDoc
  For i = 1 To .Tables.Count
    With .Tables(i)
      If Split(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "Value1" Then
        If Split(.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "Value2" Then
          .AutoFitBehavior (2)
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
```